# Gem to show countries across the world in home page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am building a application where i have to show a world map in which i have to tag all the countries from which my clients are originated. i have field in the company table which saves the country of our clients. i don't want to show the cities/streets or any other detailed information other than the country name. can anyone suggest any gem/plugin which can help me in completing this final task.

I am using ruby 1.8.7 and rails 3.0.7,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [gmaps4rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails) to display a google map. This would need:

- that you store the coordinates of the countries / or you pass a json array with these
- you set properly your map to prevent zoom

Comment: thanks dude.... but the sad news is i don't save the coordinates of the country. I do have the option to save the coordinates but the coordinates of a country will not be having z-axis, will this gem work for that...

Comment: Of course it can geocode either on save or with a method : Gmaps4rails.geocode(address_string). Check the wiki

Comment: sorry for replying late... well i checked the gem suggested by you.. but its a detailed map and i don't want use such kind of map. i want somewhat like this
[world map](http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_world.html)